Best practice for running Intel MKL-dependent program as a systemd service
We have a systemd service that looks something like
[Service]
Environment="SOME_VAR=some_value"
# etc.

ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'some command'

This service file, of course, is templated and deployed with an ansible playbook, so needs to be somewhat generic. In a few of our cases, this service needs access to the Intel MKL library, which expects that you source a shell script to set up LD_LIBRARY_PATH as well as a few other necessary variables; one could of course do
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'source /opt/intel/oneapi/mkl/2024.1/env/vars.sh && some command'

but this is very non-generic.
According to Make systemd service inherit environment variables from /etc/profile.d, it seems like this should be achievable by simply adding -l to the bash invocation, i.e.
ExecStart=/bin/bash -lc 'some command'

assuming that there is a file in /etc/profile.d/ that sources the above script.
My question(s):

Are there any issues with having the service run in a login shell?
Are there any downsides to having every similar service running in a login shell?
Is this the best way to solve this problem?


Why not simply use EnvironmentFile= instead?

The main problem is that the file in question is a script, not a file in the correct format according to https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.exec.html#EnvironmentFile=

yeah, but you assume that the script's effect can be put in /etc/profile.d, right? So, why not in your ansible role to set up these things, simply source and run the setup function once, and store the diff of env to a file?
